# passing a vector drawing to the UI thread

Tags: wpf, graphics, asynchronous

Is there any way to draw actual WPF vectorgraphics ([DrawingContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx), VisualBrush, DrawingBrush, RenderTargetBitmap etc.) with Freezables in a separate thread offscreen?

The following solution almost has it, excpet that the drawing is a bitmap and is not scalable when `this.label` becomes big you'll the the pixels.

```
private void Draw()
{
    this.dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    Thread t = new Thread(this.DrawAsync);
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

private void DrawAsync(object state)
{
    var b1 = new Button
        {
            Width = 50, 
            Height = 50, 
            Content = new TextBlock
                {
                    FontSize = 16, FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial"), FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold, Text = "Hello"
                }
        };
    b1.Measure(new Size(50, 50));
    b1.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
    PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormats.Default;
    var elementBrush = new VisualBrush(b1);
    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        // preferably I'd like to draw controls too, but shapes and text would suffice too
        dc.DrawRectangle(elementBrush, null, new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50));
        dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Green, new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), new Point(75, 25), 25, 15);
        dc.Close();
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(100, 50, 96, 96, pixelFormat);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    bitmap.Freeze();
    var br = new ImageBrush(bitmap) { Stretch = Stretch.Uniform };
    br.Freeze();
    this.dispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate { this.label.Background = br; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DrawingImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx) which is a type of freezeable. Load or fill it in a BackgroundWorker, freeze it and pass it to an Image in the Completed Event.

Comment: As soon as I draw controls using VisualBrush just like in the example in my question, I can not freeze the DrawingImage anymore. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Afair no ALL controls MUST be created in the UI Thread. Even if they are just created offscreen, as soon as you try to create it it throws an exception. Its a shame but thats the way it is. But there are otherways around that Virtualization helps with that, depending on the reason you want to do what you do.